# Find the sum $1^2+3^2+...+(2n-1)^2$ without induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I tried with $$(2n-1)^3-(2n-2)^3=12n^2-18n+7$$
Now, forming partial sums for $n=1,2,...$ 
$$(1^3-0^3)+(3^3-2^3)+...+((2n-1)^3-(2n-2)^3)=12(1^2+...+n^2)-18(1+...+n)+7n$$
How to express  $(1^3-0^3)+(3^3-2^3)+...+((2n-1)^3-(2n-2)^3)$ in general term?

Could some other method be used?

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

Your sum is

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)^2=\sum_{k=1}^n 4k^2-\sum_{k=1}^n 4k+\sum_{k=1}^n1=4\sum_{k=1}^n k^2-4\sum_{k=1}^n k+n$$

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

Let $f(n)=a_0+a_1n+a_2n^2+a_3n^3$

Write $(2n-1)^2=f(n)-f(n-1)$ to find $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3$

Answer (score 2):

why not use the formula for $\Sigma r^2$?

Comment: When I use it directly, $S_{n^2}=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ and apply it for $S_{(2n-1)^2}$ I get $S_{(2n-1)^2}=\frac{n(2n-1)(4n-1)}{3}$ I have checked for $n=3$ and this is not correct.

Comment: @no_name: You need to substract the even terms.

Comment: @no_name You can use it in user's "calculus" hint (you'll also need to use $1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ though). Also as servabat suggests $S_{(2n-1)^2}$ is $1^2+2^2+3^2+\cdots+(2n-1)^2$ and not $1^2+3^2+\cdots+(2n-1)^2$. You need to subtract the even terms inbetween.

Comment: See Ihf's answer for how to subtract the even terms.

Answer (score 2):

Note that 
$$k^2=\binom k2 +\binom {k+1}2$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n(2i-1)^2&=\sum_{i=1}^n {2i-1\choose 2}+{2i\choose 2}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\binom i2\\
&={2n+1\choose 3}\qquad\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

I love Telescoping magic $$\dfrac{4n^3}3-\dfrac{4(n-1)^3}{3}=??$$

Answer (score 1):

$
1^2+3^2+\cdots+(2n-1)^2 =
$

$\displaystyle
\quad= \sum_{k=1}^{2n} k^2 - \sum_{k=1}^{n} (2k)^2
$

$\displaystyle
\quad= \sum_{k=1}^{2n} k^2 - 4\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2
$

$
\quad= \dfrac{(2n)(2n+1)(4n+1)}{6}-\dfrac{4n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
$

$
\quad= \dfrac{n (2 n-1) (2 n+1)}{3}
$